# What does % (percent) sign in fscanf mean?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to understand somebody's code and they have

```
 while(fscanf(stdin_stream, "%*[^A-Za-z]"), fscanf(stdin_stream, "%198[a-zA-Z]", buffer) > 0)
```

What is the %198 doing to the checking of all letters in the alphabet?

And I get docked 2 points because of the question? Why? Because I ask a question on a forum made for these types of questions? A bunch of bs. Yes, I can look at the man page and I did but I didn't find one that explained it as the following answers did. I was looking for another source of information to help me, therefore I came here. But seeing I get docked points for a question is absurd.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ ?

Comment: The key to note here is that `%` is just a *character* in the *string* passed as an *argument* to `fcanf` - so consult the documentation for the consumer of said string.

Comment: Why not read the manual page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fscanf()` function uses the occurrence of `"%"` to signal that the following characters up to a letter sequence such as `"%...d"`, `"%...f"`, or `"%...[...]"` imply a follwing  augment is an address to store scanned results.

The details of the format to `fscanf()` is extensive and various on-line resource should be consulted for complete understanding.  I'll just point out a few like why 198? (which appears to be the OP's question).

`"%198[..."` assumes `buffer` can hold 198 `char` + `\0`.

Without the 198, an endless number of `char` may be save in `buffer` causing buffer over-run.

A common confusion is that the *size* of `buffer` should handle 198+1 `char`.

```
char buffer[198+1];
fscanf(stdin_stream, "%198[a-zA-Z]", buffer);
```